# perl MakeMaker makefile with submodules

Tags: perl, makefile, makemaker

I have created a perl modul with 3 submodules. I want to create a makefile with MakeMaker and have a problem.

My structure of my module is
 /module.pm and /module/sub.pm.

If i create the makefile only the module.pm file will be included. Which parameter i need to write in the makemaker so the submodules are included too?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put your module in the root directory of your distribution.  Instead, create a `lib` subdirectory and put all the modules under it:

```
Makefile.PL
lib/module.pm
lib/module/sub.pm
```

The `Makefile.PL` should automatically notice all modules under `lib`.  You shouldn't have to change anything except any paths pointing to modules (e.g. `VERSION_FROM`).

If your module has a prefix, include that under the `lib` directory.  If your module is named Some::Other::Module, you'd have:

```
Makefile.PL
lib/Some/Other/Module.pm
lib/Some/Other/Module/Sub.pm
```

Comment: @TobiasToasty, then show more details.  Show us your Makefile.PL.  Show us your whole directory structure.  Show us the output from `make`.

Comment: After i added the submodules to the manifest everything works fine. Thank you so much :)